# Why isn't it checking for the correct value? (Javascript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckPwd()
{
 if(document.forms['frm'].pass.value == "magicisreal")
    {
      alert('Welcome, ADMIN...');
      return true;
    }
      return false;
}
</script>

Password:
<br>
<input type="password" name="pass">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Continue" onclick="return CheckPwd()">

</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to return an alert when the value "magicisreal" is entered into the textbox. What, exactly, am I doing wrong that is not causing this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,there is no form named frm.
So, the if statement you are checking is not valid.
use the following code snippet to achieve what you are looking for :

```html
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckPwd()
{
var password = document.getElementById('pass-input').value;
console.log(password);
 if(password == "magicisreal")
    {
      alert('Welcome, ADMIN...');
      return true;
    }
      return false;
}
</script>

Password:
<br>
<input type="password"  id="pass-input" name="pass">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Continue"  onclick="CheckPwd()">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Form. Try this -

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function CheckPwd() {
    if (document.forms['frm'].pass.value == "magicisreal") {
      alert('Welcome, ADMIN...');
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
</script>

Password:
<br>
<form name="frm">
  <input type="password" name="pass">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Continue" onclick="return CheckPwd()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `document.forms` which expects that `form` exists in your HTML but you have not defined that.
Just define the HTML form either with `name=frm`.

```js
function CheckPwd() {
    if(document.forms["frm"].pass.value == "magicisreal") {
        alert('Welcome, ADMIN...');
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <form name="frm" action="">
    Password:
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="pass">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" onclick="return CheckPwd()">
    </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```